# Help, tor wont load. "general SOCKS server failure"

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

3/12/2016 2:17:31 AM.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
3/12/2016 2:17:47 AM.900 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
3/12/2016 2:17:55 AM.300 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
3/12/2016 2:17:55 AM.300 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
3/12/2016 2:17:57 AM.900 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 104.131.108.182:56880 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
3/12/2016 2:18:37 AM.500 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.11:49868 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
3/12/2016 2:18:38 AM.300 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 83.212.101.3:41213 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
3/12/2016 2:18:50 AM.300 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.105.109.147:13764 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
3/12/2016 2:18:54 AM.500 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.13:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
3/12/2016 2:18:56 AM.400 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 198.245.60.50:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
3/12/2016 2:18:56 AM.400 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.12:80 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
3/12/2016 2:18:56 AM.400 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 192.99.11.54:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
3/12/2016 2:18:56 AM.400 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.105.109.165:10527 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
3/12/2016 2:18:56 AM.400 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.10:41835 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
3/12/2016 2:24:47 AM.500 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
3/12/2016 2:24:47 AM.500 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
3/12/2016 2:24:47 AM.500 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150

Comment: Please add your logs to the question so we can take a closer look.